# javascript php mysql flot database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, flot

everyone! I have issues with regard to my x-axis. I'm using the api of flot. In my case, I'm extracting data from mysql to plot the graph. Both axes requires data to be extracted from mysql. For example, mysql will extract a data for the Y axis, say 20. My x axis will extract data from mysql of that particular time.
I tried to rewrite the script a few times, but to no conclusion. I tried attempting to create a variable, options, but it didn't work. It works only if I place the x axis statement just below y. The whole idea of creating a new variable options because I wanted to do a loop for the x-axis to continouous collect data from mysql. In the below quote, I simulated it with selected arrays.

```
$(function () {
var graph = [];
var power = <?php echo json_encode($data);?>;
var time = <?php echo json_encode($times);?>;
var row = <?php echo json_encode($nrow);?>;
//alert(time.toSource());




for (var i = 1; i < row; i += 1) {

//var test = time[i];
//alert(test);
//graph.push([i, power[i]]);

var hhmm = time[i].split(":");

var hh = parseInt(hhmm[0]);
var mm = parseInt(hhmm[1])/60;
var tt = hh+mm;
//var tx = hh;

graph.push([tt, power[i]]);
```

}

```
var options = {
xaxis: { ticks:[[1,time[1]],[2,time[2]],[3,time[3]],[4,time[4]],[5,time[5]],[6,time[6]],[7,time[7]],[8,time[8]]]}
```

};

//alert(options.toSource());

```
var plot = $.plot($("#placeholder"), 
       [ { data: graph, label: "Power" } ], {
           series: {
               lines: { show: true },
               points: { show: true }
           },
           grid: { hoverable: true, clickable: true },
           yaxis: { min: 0, max: 25 },
           //xaxes: [ { mode: 'time' } ]
           //xaxis: { mode: "time"}
           //xaxis: { mode: "time",timeformat:"%H/%M" }
           //xaxis: { ticks:[[1,time[1]],[2,time[2]],[3,time[3]],[4,time[4]],[5,time[5]],[6,time[6]],[7,time[7]]]}


       }), options);
```

I have changed the options function, but it doesn't work.

```
var options = {
series: {
               lines: { show: true },
               points: { show: true }
           },
           grid: { hoverable: true, clickable: true },
           yaxis: { min: 0, max: 25 },
           for (var i = 1; i < row; i += 1) 
           {
             xaxis: { ticks:[[i,time[i]]}
             };
```

};

Comment: var options = {
    series: {
                   lines: { show: true },
                   points: { show: true }
               },
               grid: { hoverable: true, clickable: true },
               yaxis: { min: 0, max: 25 },
               for (var i = 1; i < row; i += 1) 
               {
                 xaxis: { ticks:[[i,time[i]]}
                 };
};

Comment: Please edit you question and supply an example of what `xaxis` should look like.

Answer (score 0):

If I've surmised the format you wish for `xaxis` correctly, you could try the following:

```
var ticks = [];
for (var i = 1; i < row; i += 1)
{
  ticks.push ([i, time[i]]);
}
var xaxis = {
  ticks: ticks,
  // ... any additional properties...
};
```

This will create an object `xaxis` with the property `ticks` which in turn is an array of arrays where each sub-array has two elements, the counter starting with one and the value of the `time` array for each `i`. I suppose you'll want to use code similar to this to create `options`:

```
var options = {
  series: { lines: { show: true },
  points: { show: true } },
  grid: { hoverable: true, clickable: true },
  yaxis: { min: 0, max: 25 },
  xaxis: xaxis
};
```

You cannot use the `for()` statement in the object initialization, you'll have to create the `xaxis` array before, and use the variable name when creating the `options` object.